# How to add local Drush with Composer to a XAMPP Drupal on Windows?

Tags: drush, 9

I have installed Drupal 9 on XAMPP in Windows 11.

How could I add local Drush with Composer to a XAMPP Drupal on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Drush install webpage](https://www.drush.org/latest/install/):

```
composer require drush/drush
```

Comment: But how can this command run on `C:\xampp\htdocs\web_application_root`?

Comment: OP has a non-Composerized project.

Comment: Indeed, I want to compose the non composed XAMPP installation.

Comment: Drupal 9 is composerized out-of-the-box, even a tarball/zip. If you have [composer installed](https://getcomposer.org/download/) this answer should work.

Comment: @4uk4 – Isn't this dangerous if OP already has manually downloaded other contrib modules? Or will the paths be preserved?

Comment: leymannx thank you for asking that, it shows my question is valuable.